# Remove white spaces in text file and overwrite inplace

Tags: python, list, text

How to check every line in a text file and remove white spaces at the beginning of each line?

Here is what I tried, but it gives me a blank file instead

```
with open("0.txt","r") as readfile, open("0.txt","w") as outfile:
    for line in readfile:
        if line.startswith(' '):
            outfile.write(line.replace(' ', ''))
```

Comment: You are reading and writing from the same file (`0. text`), `open` creates a new file,  use different file name for writing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change file in-place I suggest using built-in module named `fileinput`.

```
import fileinput 
for line in fileinput.input("0.txt", inplace=True):
    print(line.lstrip(), end="")
```

Note that I specified empty `end` as these lines already have trailing newlines. If you want to know more about that module I suggest reading [PyMOTW3 article](https://pymotw.com/3/fileinput/index.html).